# Simplify expression Boolean-Algebra

Tags: math, boolean-logic, simplify

For my class I have to study some Boolean algebra. Now I'm having some difficulties with simplifying expression.

For example I get:

```
A.B.C + NOT(A) + NOT(B) + NOT(C)
```

I tried checking wolfram alpha but there's not simplification showing up there.
Can you tell me how to simplify this expression?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `.` indicate AND, and `+` indicate OR? If so, the entire thing simplifies to TRUE.

Comment: By simplifying I mean going form **(A+B+C).(A.NOT(B).NOT(C)).NOT(C)** to **B.NOT(C)** @ChrisTaylor

Comment: You've only accepted an answer once of the 7 questions you've asked.  If you've received value, please remember to vote up all good, helpful answers and [accept the most useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) to you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Boolean Algebraic Solution (using a more traditional notation):

Given Boolean expression:

```
abc + a' + b' + c'
```

Apply double negation:

```
(abc + a' + b' + c')''
```

Apply De Morgan's Law for a disjunction:

```
((abc)'a''b''c'')'
```

Reduce double negations:

```
((abc)'abc)'
```

AND of x and x' is 0:

```
(0)'
```

Negation of 0 is 1:

```
1
```

### Boolean Algebraic Solution (using the given notation):

Given Boolean expression:

```
a.b.c + NOT(a) + NOT(b) + NOT(c)
```

Apply double negation:

```
NOT(NOT(a.b.c + NOT(a) + NOT(b) + NOT(c)))
```

Apply De Morgan's Law for a disjunction:

```
NOT(NOT(a.b.c).NOT(NOT(a)).NOT(NOT(b)).NOT(NOT(c))))
```

Reduce double negations:

```
NOT(NOT(a.b.c).a.b.c)
```

AND of x and x' is 0:

```
NOT(0)
```

Negation of 0 is 1:

```
1
```

Answer (score 3):

Truth table:

```
A    B    C    X
0    0    0    1
0    0    1    1
0    1    0    1
0    1    1    1
1    0    0    1
1    0    1    1
1    1    0    1
1    1    1    1
```

So the simplification is just:

```
X = 1
```

Comment: The question was "how". Could you explain your answer?

Comment: Yes, one way to simplify an expression is to write it out as a truth table as above, and the then collect terms (they should have already covered this in your course?) - in this case there is just one term, so the solution is trivial.

Comment: XD it's not for my course, I already know all this stuff. The question was asking how to simplify the expression. I understand what you did with the truth table but, to the person who asked the question you just tossed out a bunch of numbers and said "Tada!" I thought maybe you would explain how you arrived at your answer from a truth table as opposed to constructing a karnaugh map or applying DeMorgan's laws to the expression.

Comment: My mistake - I thought you were the OP. Anyway, when I started to write out the truth table I didn't realise the answer was going to be trivial - if it has been a more interesting expression I would have gone into more detail. As it was though there was really nothing to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha wasn't giving a simplification because it didn't understand your notation.  Using `(A and B and C) or NOT(A) or NOT(B) or NOT(C)` [shows](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A+and+B+and+C%29+or+NOT%28A%29+or+NOT%28B%29+or+NOT%28C%29) that it simplifies to true.

Or you can just look at it: if any are false, the `NOT` will makke everything true, and if they're all true, then so is the first clause.

Comment: The question was "how". Could you explain your answer?

Comment: First paragraph: "You can simplify this expression using Wolfram Alpha if you use notation it recognizes."  Second paragraph: "You can simplify this in your head by looking at each of the four `OR`ed terms, and determining what will make that true."

Comment: "look at it in your head" isn't a very specific answer, you haven't qualified "head" or the sort of things this "head" is supposed to do. If I grab a stuffed teddy bear it does indeed have a head, but I have my doubts that it will give the same answer as you did. "simplify using wolfram" does clearly express how to enter the data into the program but still does not explain the process of simplification. Likely, for someone trying to learn how to simplify logical expressions, the usage of a program to provide the answer would be to verify if their own work is on track.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

```
A AND B = NOT(NOT(A) OR NOT(B))

A OR B = NOT(NOT(A) AND NOT(B))
```

and the normal methods for distribution, commutation, etc. See 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws

Note that in the linked texts above the symbols are written differently.

- AND is ∧
- OR is ∨
- NOT is ¬